# Need Programmer's Reference Manual TI Stellaris LM4F120H5QR

Tags: microcontroller, arm, texas-instruments, reference, reference-materials

Just searched the Texas Instruments' website for `LM4F120H5QR  Programmer's Reference Manual`

Found nothing.

Example...

While stepping through some code, I come across this instruction...

```
  0x4E:  0xdbfg  BLT.N   0x44
```

...and I want to see what flags affect this instruction, and how the decision is made.

I thought that the name of the document that explains this was The *Programmer's Reference Manual*.

Evidently not, because I can find no such manual on TI's webpage which has the docs for this chip ([THIS PAGE](http://www.ti.com/product/TM4C1233H6PM/technicaldocuments) is the only place I knew to look for it).

Question: What is the name of the manual I want ?

Question: Where do I find it ?

Comment: This was a weird one. When they introduced the stellaris launchpad, there was a lot of hype over it especially for its price $5-$10 a dev board. Then a few months later, after the TIVA series came out, all reference to the LM4F120 sort of just disappeared and the stellaris launchpad only referenced the TIVA IC. It was really weird.

Comment: So are they selling an undocumented product ?

Comment: They don't sell it anymore. You can't buy the LM4F anymore. When the docs started disappearing, so did the ICs. You can still buy the launchpads, but they will have a TIVA series IC on it. If you bought it recently, you didn't buy it from TI or your distributor has some old stock that they are trying to get rid of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TI rebranded the Stellaris LM4F120 part as the Tiva TM4C123 part.  They're nearly identical and the documentation, driver software, and example code is mostly interchangeable.  They both use an ARM Cortex-M4 core.  When I want to learn details about core instructions I check the ARM documentation, [Cortex-M4 Instruction Set](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/CIHJJEIH.html)

Comment: Okay, just spent 20 minutes with that site.  Downloaded the PDF file.  Searched for `BLT.N` which I see on my debug screen.  Not there in the PDF file, nor did the search function of that site return it.  Is this documented ? Or is it one of the things that you have to pick up from guessing and asking questions online ?

Comment: It's a condition branch instruction `B{cond}` with the `LT`, "less than" condition.

Comment: I guessed at that part, although it was less than obvious in the documentation; so thanks for the confirmation. It really helps. My quandary now is:  What does the `.N` mean ?

Comment: See section 3.3.8 Instruction Width Selection.  The .N suffix forces a 16-bit instruction encoding.

Comment: Aha, there it is !  How on earth could I have missed something __SO OBVIOUS__ !!  Thanks for the clue.  Plus 1 and the answer.  Thanks, for real.